# invalid operands of types ‘double’ snd const char [3]’ to binary 'operator<<'

Tags: c++, increment, decrement

This is the error message I get when I try to build:

> invalid operands of types ‘double’ snd const char [3]’ to binary 'operator<<'

Obviously I'm really new to this. Any help would be appreciated.

The code reads:

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;


 int main () 
 {
     double x = 3;
     double y = 4;

     cout << "(" << x = y++ << ", " << y << ")" << endl;
     cout << "(" << x = ++y << ", " << y << ")" << endl;
     cout << "(" << x = y-- << ", " << y << ")" << endl;
     cout << "(" << x = --y << ", " << y << ")" << endl;

         return 0;
 }
```

Comment: you need parenthesis: `cout << "(" << (x = y++) << ", " << y << ")" << endl;`

Answer (score 1):

`=` has a lower precedence than `<<`, change it to:

```
std::cout << "(" << (x = y++) << ", " << y << ")" << std::endl;
//                  ^       ^
```

See [C++ Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Answer (score 0):

Assignment (`=`) has a lower [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than shift (`<<`), so you need parantheses to get the meaning you expect:

```
cout << "(" << (x = y++) << ", " << y << ")" << endl;
               ^       ^
```

But you shouldn't be writing code with multiple side-effects like this: the evaluation order of the operands isn't specified, and this sort of thing can easily lead to undefined behaviour. Keep your code simple, doing one thing at a time.